# Переопределение стандартных классов и литералов в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, наследование, переопределение

Можно ли полностью переопределить стандартные классы и литералы в Python?

Например, чтобы получить другое строковое представление\репрезентацию или добавить условие к элементам при создании.

---

Допустим, это будет список (`list`), у которого я хочу убрать пробелы в строковом представлении, как просили в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/990855/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) вопросе.

Пока что у меня получилось создать класс, унаследовав его от `list`:

```py
class list(list):
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__().replace(' ', '')


x = list((5, 2, 3))
print(x)                # [5,2,3]

x = [5, 2, 3]           # Литералы тут не относятся к моему классу, а хотелось бы
print(x)                # [5, 2, 3]

print(list('spam'))     # ['s','p','a','m']
```

---

Но это не то, что я хотел бы.

Во первых, это неудобно, как Вы уже могли заметить.
А во вторых, я хочу, чтобы класс переопределился глобально:

- При использовании литералов списка (`[]`), вызывался бы мой конструктор
- Функция `type` возвращала бы `<class 'list'>` (сейчас `<class '__main__.list'>`)
  и т. д.

---

***P. S.:** Это ужасное архитектурное решение. Я никогда не собираюсь использовать это, но мне очень интересно лучше узнать Python и его возможности.*

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, в питоне все стандартные классы, название которых пишется с маленькой буквы, написаны на с++ и вшиты глубоко в ядро питона. Так что вряд ли в них удастся вклиниться, не переписывая сам интерпретатор.

Comment: @Xander Я совсем не против переписать эту часть кода ради эксперимента ;). Только бы узнать, где именно стоит искать.

Comment: Если говорить про `__repr__`, то вроде это здесь https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L383

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если в двух словах, то переопределить литералы не получится.

Литерал списка это самостоятельный элемент синтаксиса python

```py
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("['x', 'y', 'z']", 'eval'))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=List(elts=[Str(s='x'), Str(s='y'), Str(s='z')], ctx=Load()))])"
```

При компиляции в байткод он транслируется в серию инструкций, загружающих элементы в стек и строящих из них список.

```py
>>> dis.dis(lambda: ['x', 'y', 'z'])
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('x')
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('y')
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 ('z')
              6 BUILD_LIST               3
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Вот так CPython интерпретирует инструкцию [`BUILD_LIST`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L2689) (язык C)

```c
case TARGET(BUILD_LIST): {
    PyObject *list =  PyList_New(oparg);
    if (list == NULL)
        goto error;
    while (--oparg >= 0) {
        PyObject *item = POP();
        PyList_SET_ITEM(list, oparg, item);
    }
    PUSH(list);
    DISPATCH();
}
```

Т.е. выполняет функцию [`PyObject * PyList_New(Py_ssize_t size)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L155), создающую список из `size` неинициализированных элементов.
Затем выталкивает нужное количество элементов из стека и помещает их в созданный список.

`PyList_New` создает объект встроенного типа [`PyList_Type`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L3003) с соответствующей ему структурой данных [`PyListObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/listobject.h#L23)

```c
op = PyObject_GC_New(PyListObject, &PyList_Type);
```

и выделяет память под элементы списка

```c
op->ob_item = (PyObject **) PyMem_Calloc(size, sizeof(PyObject *));
```

Никакой речи о явном обращении к типу `list`, будь то встроенному или пользовательскому, не идет вовсе. `list` это всего лишь интерфейс, позволяющий коду на python работать со встроенным в интерпретатор типом `PyList_Type`. Интерпретатор же в этом примере работает с ним напрямую. Поэтому подмена или удаление типа из `builtins` ничего не дает.

В теории конечно же можно модифицировать синтаксический анализатор, либо компилятор байткода, либо его интерпретатор, но, думаю, очевидно, что

- Работать это будет только в вашей измененной версии интерпретатора
- Не факт, что такие изменения не повлекут за собой потерю работоспособности существующего кода: если интерпретатор хочет видеть настоящий список, он может быть совершенно не готов к тому, что ему подсовывают сабкласс
- Если интерпретатору придется обращаться к медленному пользовательскому коду ради таких элементарных вещей, производительность, без преувеличения, упадет в разы.

Answer (score -2):

Это чудовищно, но можно попробовать так:

```
import builtins

builtins.list = NewClass_List
```

Comment: По сути, это то, что я уже сделал. Литералы не признают этот класс :), а функция `type` возвращает `<class '__main__.NewClass_List'>`.