# Разделение число на разряды Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такая переменная Python `money = 123456` Есть идеи, как превратить ее в `money = 123,456`? Но она может поменяться, например в `money = 12345`, и надо чтобы она стала `money = 12,345`. Т.е сама задача - разделить число на разряды, но чтобы оно осталось `int()` числом

Comment: я что-то не понял, что значит "разделить на разряды, но чтобы оно осталось int числом".

Comment: А почему бы просто не делить число на 1000?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как пример:

```
"{:,}".format(number)
```

Взято [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators/10742904#10742904).

Comment: Элегантное решение! :)

Comment: У вас получилась строка, а не int

Comment: number осталось int.

Comment: Технически это всё-таки неверно. Возвращается же строка, просто преобразуется неявно, непосредственно в `format` методе. Но вопрос автора неясен изначально, а Ваш способ очень уж хорош. :)

Comment: @nomnoms12 Ну технически и 123456 хранится не как 123456 ;) А способ не мой, я ж его подглядел когда-то :) Он вообще в каком-то PEP описан.

Answer (score 2):

Это невозможно. Вы не сможете изменить репрезентацию стандартного типа. Я как-то задавал похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/990901/339283).

Единственное, что Вы можете, это преобразовать число в строку, разделив разряды, например, с помощью регулярного выражения.

*Пример:*

```py
import re

string = str(123456789)

res = re.sub(r'\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))', r'\g<0>,', string)
print(res)
```

*stdout:*

```html
123,456,789
```

Comment: Или так: `string[:-3] + ',' + string[-3:]`

Comment: @gil9red Это неуниверсальное решение (только для выделения 1 разряда), а регулярное выражение поможет при любой длине числа.

Comment: Вы правы, подумал, что нужно только один разряд :)