# Изменение встроенного метода Python OOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, dict

Поставлена задача создать класс словарей `MyDict` так, чтобы метод `get()` по умолчанию возвращал не **`None`**, а **`0`**.

Написал так:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def get(self, key, default_value=0):
        if key in self.keys():
            return self[key]
        else:
            return default_value
```

И если делать так:

```
new_dict = MyDict()
new_dict['Ikari'] = 1
new_dict['Asuka'] = 2
new_dict['Rei'] = 3
print(new_dict.get('Misato'))
```

то все работает.

---

Но если присваивать сразу:

```
new_dict = MyDict()
new_dict = {'Ikari': 1,
         'Asuka': 2,
         'Rei': 3
         }
```

то `new_dict.get('Misato')` вернет **`None`**. Видимо присваивание с фигурными скобками автоматом создает объект встроенного класса (?).

Что тут можно сделать несложного, без переписывания типа `dict` со всеми методами?

Comment: Присваивание всегда заменяет старый объект (если он был записан в переменную) на новый. Создание словаря через фигурные скобки всегда создает стандартный словарь. В целом, при присваивании в переменную нового значения тип старого значения никак не учитывается.

Comment: @insolor Что-то можно было бы сделать только если на стандартный `dict` можно было бы навесить метакласс. Но я так понимаю этого нельзя.

Comment: @CrazyElf не знаю как бы это выглядело, но и не понятно зачем. С чего вообще стандартный конструктор словаря должен как-то учитывать тип объекта, который раньше в переменной лежал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def get(self, key, default_value=0):
        if key in self.keys():
            return self[key]
        else:
            return default_value

new_dict = MyDict({'Ikari': 1, 'Asuka': 2, 'Rei': 3}) 
print(f"Misato: {new_dict.get('Misato')}")
print(f"Asuka : {new_dict.get('Asuka')}")
```

> Misato: 0
> Asuka : 2

Answer (score 2):

Вы переопределяете переменную `new_dict` новым экземпляром словаря. Причём это будет экземпляр стандартного типа `dict` без переопределённого метода:

```py
new_dict = MyDict()                            # <class '__main__.MyDict'>
new_dict = {'Ikari': 1, 'Asuka': 2, 'Rei': 3}  # <class 'dict'>
```

Вы не сможете ничего с этим сделать. Создание объектов с использованием литералов всегда будет возвращать стандартные типы данных. Переопределить их в коде не получится

Comment: А если метаклассы применить, тоже нельзя? )  Я просто спрашиваю. Вроде метаклассы умеют управлять классами

Comment: @CrazyElf Пару лет назад я задавал [такой же вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/990901/339283), только там были списки. Оказалось, что нельзя. По аналогии нельзя и со словарями

Comment: Ответ ниже опровергает ваше высказывание.